# Puppet: removing a package with --nodeps

Tags: package, uninstallation, rpm, puppet

Is there a method to remove a package without dependency removal? Essentially I would like to do the following command with puppet.

rpm -e package --nodeps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write an exec inside a user define type if you want specifically that command :

```
/etc/puppet/module/modulename/manifests/rmpack.pp

define modulename::rmpack {
    exec { 'remove_${name}' :
       command => "rpm -e ${name} --nodeps",
       path => "/bin/rpm",
       onlyif => "rpm -q --quiet ${name}",
    }
}
```

In your manifest `/etc/puppet/module/manifests/init.pp`, call the user define type :

```
rmpack { "emacs-nox" : }
```